# I updated Debian Squeeze and Linux Mint is now missing from GRUB

Tags: linux, debian, grub, linux-mint

I did a search for how to fix this and came up with nothing...I would like to put Linux Mint back on GRUB. I am a newbie so please be easy on me.

I installed Linux Mint first, then Debian Squeeze. Upon updating Squeeze, I do not have Mint on GRUB anymore. How do I add Mint back to GRUB?

Hopefully, I asked this question correctly. Sorry if I did not. Hopefully someone can still point me in the right direction.

Comment: Before looking into your problem, can you confirm that you didn't erase Linux Mint?  i.e., you did not install Debian Squeeze on top of it?  The two operating systems should be on separate partitions.  There are command-line tools like fdisk to check; but install gparted and run it for a visual view of your hard disk.  Debian may have created more than one partition; but at least one should belong to Linux Mint.  Of course, if you cannot find Linux Mint, you must have erased it...  Debian usually adds other OS to the GRUB list automatically during its install process...

Comment: I should have clarified that...when I first installed Debian, I was able to use Mint. I updated Debian about 2 or 3 days ago and now all of a sudden Mint is not on GRUB. To be sure, I just checked in case my daughter messed with something. I can access the filesystem for Mint.

Comment: Just checked to make sure I did not erase it. Mint is still there and is on /dev/sda1 as ext4 partition. To be clear, Mint was on GRUB, but after update it is not there anymore.

Comment: It may help to paste your grub config.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that? I'm not quirensurebhowbto do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer after searching for the last couple of weeks:

In terminal type the following:

```
su
<enter your password>
update-grub
```

This will automatically create a new grub.conf and hopefully auto-detect your other operating systems. I desperately tried this and it detected Linux Mint and Debian Squeeze and updated the bootloader to reflect both of those operating systems.